# Understanding the limits of Cloud Firestore's security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm writing the security rules for my Firestore database, and I got to the point where I'm probably writing too many checks and the authorization automatically fails.

For example the rules for a specific path are

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /pending/{userId} {
      match /rate/{vendorId}/events/{eventId}/ratings/{rateId} {
        allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId
            && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/vendors/$(vendorId)) // The vendor must exist
            && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId)/subscriptions/$(vendorId)) // The user must be subscribed to the vendor
            && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/vendors/$(vendorId)/events/$(eventId)) //  The event must exist
            && !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/vendors/$(vendorId)/events/$(eventId)/ratings/$(userId)) // The user must not have already voted for the event
      }
    }
  }
}
```

These rules apply when writing to /pending/{userId}/rate/{vendorId}/events/{eventId}/ratings/{rateId}

Removing one or a combination of rules makes everything work again.
I read on the documentation about a limit of 10 developer-defined functions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#developer_defined), but exists and get are listed as service-defined and should not be counted. Even if they were, here I'm only using five.

Is there a more efficient way to check the same fields? How do I calculate how much a single line counts into reaching the 10 functions limit?

Thanks

Comment: The "10 limit" is not a factor here.  It is on call **depth**: _The call depth is limited to 10 function invocations_

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm actually not sure on how I can determine the call depth for my database rules. Just searching "call depth" did not return a lot of information, could you link me some resources that might be useful? Even a few examples might be good enough.

Comment: Suppose you wrote functions A, B, C where A called B, which called C. A rule that invoked A would have a call depth of 3.  Call depth is not the cause of the problem you are experiencing.  Your post indicates you can comment out any one of the lines and the rule works.  Is that right?

Comment: Oh okay, thank you, that's really simple! And yes, commenting any line solves the problem (haven't tried the very first one)

Comment: Please update your post to show the entire rule, starting with `match`.

Comment: I updated the code in the post, it now shows the entire rules file (minus rules for other paths that should not matter here)

Comment: I copied your rule and was able to reproduce the behavior you describe.  Very odd.  Suggest you contact [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/).

Comment: I contacted support, I'll update the post once I get some more data. That's very odd indeed. Again, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Firebase PM here: Currently, we limit the number of `get()` and `exists()` calls in a given rule evaluation to three, which is why you're seeing the behavior fail after adding the fourth. I'll make sure the docs are appropriately updated to include this info.

EDIT (4/2/18): These limits are now documented: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#security_rule_limits

EDIT (5/14/18): We increased the limit to 10: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#security_rule_limits

`get()` and `exists()` calls are more computationally expensive than "normal" rule evaluations, and we want to ensure a tight bound on evaluation time, so as to not slow down incoming requests. I'm pretty sure we can increase the number greater than three, but be aware that we'll look up all of these keys/values and it may take a little longer/cost a little more to evaluate each request.

Note that in this specific case, you're able to do this with three calls:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /pending/{userId} {
      match /rate/{vendorId}/events/{eventId}/ratings/{rateId} {
        // Only allow a document to be created
        allow create:
            // The user must not have already voted for the event
            if request.auth.uid == userId
            && request.auth.uid == rateId
            // The vendor must exist
            && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/vendors/$(vendorId)) 
            // The user must be subscribed to the vendor
            && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId)/subscriptions/$(vendorId)) 
            //  The event must exist
            && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/vendors/$(vendorId)/events/$(eventId));
        // Not necessary unless you want to allow updates
        allow update: if ...;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for taking the time to address this. I'm sure the updated documentation will help a lot of people who might have the same issue in the future.

I'd like to ask you one more thing, just to decide on how to do things in the future: more complex apps might reach any limits you put on exists() calls, so I guess my way of doing security checks is inherently flawed. 

Should I check all of these fields in the function itself? Or is there a better way to ensure only the 'right' user can perform an action (other than client-side checks)?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, finally took a deeper look here. You can solve this problem with 3 calls (the last call is not necessary, as you've got the data already).